# unable to connect to an INTERNET in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

in My mobile application i want to fetch some data from server.
I have read many article that the cause of my error is 
not having this code on xml file

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

but i have added this in my config file. still my app is unable to fetch data from server 
please help

Comment: Try using https://github.com/lukesmith123/whitelist-2/tree/18a8ce4

Comment: how do i use it on my file .. please help me out in this

Comment: with this less information we're not able to help you

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I recommend you to make sure you have installed plugins mentioned below.

> cordova-plugin-network-information
>
> cordova-plugin-whitelist

for more information about these plugins please visit [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist)
and [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-network-information).

In case still its not working then please add below tags in your **platforms/android/androidManifest.xml** file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can install whitelist plugin using

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

command from CLI.

After that add `<access>` tags in `config.xml`

P.S. It's not good idea to add `<access origin="*"/>`, so add `<access>` tags only for the domains you will fetch data.

Some expamples of `<access>` tags.

```
<!-- Allow images, xhrs, etc. to google.com -->
<access origin="http://google.com" />
<access origin="https://google.com" />

<!-- Access to the subdomain maps.google.com -->
<access origin="http://maps.google.com" />

<!-- Access to all the subdomains on google.com -->
<access origin="http://*.google.com" />
```

You can read more at Plugin's documentation https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist